# Table Row Click, External loading

Tags: jquery, html, css

Please view:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-load-in-and-animate-content-with-jquery/

I want to do everything that the demo does, only using a table row click instead of an a href link. How do i do this?

***EDIT***

This is the code im trying to use:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {  

    // Check for hash value in URL  
    var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);  
    var href = $('#MyTable_ID tr td').each(function(){  
        var href = $(this).attr('href');  
        if(hash==href.substr(0,href.length-5)){  
            var toLoad = hash+'.html #DivContent_ID';  
            $('#DivContent_ID').load(toLoad)  
        }  
    });  

    $('#MyTable_ID tr td').click(function(){  

    var toLoad = $(this).attr('rel')+' #DivFromExternalPage';  
    $('#DivContent_ID').hide('fast',loadContent);  
    $('#load').remove();  
    $('#wrapper').append('<span id="load">LOADING...</span>');  
    $('#load').fadeIn('normal');  
    window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(0,$(this).attr('href').length-5);  
    function loadContent() {  
        $('#DivContent_ID').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())  
    }  
    function showNewContent() {  
        $('#DivContent_ID').show('normal',hideLoader());  
    }  
    function hideLoader() {  
        $('#load').fadeOut('normal');  
    }  
    return false;  

    });  
});  
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

add a table with an id, such as id='links'

like

```
<table id='links'>
  <tr>
    <td rel='index.html'>index</td>
```

and then change

```
$('#nav li a').click(function(){ //change the targeted element
var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #content'; //was the source of the URL we needed
```

to

```
$('#links tr td').click(function(){ //changed to the td inside a ID'd table
var toLoad = $(this).attr('rel')+' #content'; //the rel attribute now holds that URL for us...
```

Comment: Please take a look at my edited question and view the code im currently trying. Its not working for me at the moment.