# Click table row to load new table

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, click

So I have a table loaded on the my page, Is it possible to click on a row and have it load another table with the same ID from my database?  For instance a table with customer orders is already loaded, when i click on one of the rows is it possible to have a second table load with the order record with the same id?

This is my code loading the first table. I was thinking maybe i could use a check box value? Or maybe some sort of jquery all though I dont know much about jquerys

I was able to find this code that prints the selected row to a message box but Im not sure how or even if it can do what ive described?
this is essentially what i want to do http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cobidLA_KVU&feature=youtu.be

```
 <table border="5",th,td, cellspacing="5", cellpadding="5", width="500", align="center">
            <tr>
                <th>TP ID</th>
                <th>Permit Deny</th>
                <th>Level</th>
                <th>Session</th>
                <th>Information Specialist</th>
            </tr>

            <?php foreach ($results as $row): ?>

            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row->TP_ID ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->Permit_or_Deny ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->Level ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->Session ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->Information_specialist ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach ?>

        </table>



 var i = 1;
    $('td').each(function(){    
        $(this).addClass('col'+i);
        i = i+1;
    });

    $('table').find("td:not(.col4)").on('click',function(){
        alert($(this).text());
    })
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Table Row Click, External loading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804890/table-row-click-external-loading)

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick reply, doesnt that load links though? I want to load values from my database into another table by clicking on a row sort of like this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cobidLA_KVU&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 0):

You can also use jQuery/Ajax. Make a $_GET from it and request the server for a new GET variable.